# New user can't change password in Meteor

Tags: meteor

When I add a new user, and open the link in the received verification email, the new user is logged in but can't change password. When I go to "Change password", I leave "current password" blank, type a password and click "Change password" and get the error "Match failed".

The user is created with a Meteor.call from the client to the following method:

```
Meteor.methods({
  createUser: function(user) {
    var userID = Accounts.createUser({
      username: user.username,
      email: user.email,
      profile: {
        firstName: user.firstName,
        lastName: user.lastName,
      }
    });
    Accounts.sendVerificationEmail(userID); 
  }
});
```

I have the following settings for Accounts.config and Accounts.ui.config:

```
Accounts.ui.config({
    passwordSignupFields: 'USERNAME_AND_EMAIL'
})

Accounts.config({
    forbidClientAccountCreation: false,
    sendVerificationEmail: true
})
```

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you leave current password blank?

When creating an account you must specify a password otherwise it is considered null.

Try passing in `password: ""` when creating it if you intend to change it this way.

I would recommend you write a method to change it if you want them to enter a password after they have verified their account. Something like this:

```
Meteor.methods('changeMyPassword':function(newPassword) {
    Accounts.setPassword(this.userId, newPassword);
});
```

The intention of the account verification email is that you create the account with a specified password and verify it after you've created the account.

Example of how to use [Accounts.createUser](http://meteorexamples.com/example/Tt58nZgr6tGsYq5Hu)

Comment: The case was the empty password. I already tried with `password: ""`, but with the same result. But your reply still counts as an answer :-) Thanks!

Comment: does Accounts.setPassword(this.userId, newPassword);  still exist in Meteor ? i have undefined function when i call it

Comment: @Genjuro yes it still exists (https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/accounts-password/password_server.js#L327-L342). Make sure you've added `accounts-password`